No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource, CORS error in MERN app
I was working on a project to create a simple payments app and during deployment when I tried to log in to the app I got the below error:
signin:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mere-paise-nikal-backend.onrender.com/api/v1/user/signin' from origin 'https://mere-paise-nikal.onrender.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Now I know what a cors error is and I have included app.use(cors()) in my code but still i am facing this issue.
I deployed the app on render.
Initially, it was working fine but then I copied the project directory to a different directory and after that, it stopped working.
I thought there might be some issues with dependencies and i reinstalled cors but still i cannot resolve the issue.
I would be great if someone could just help me out.
Here is my index.js


const express = require("express");
const mainRouter = require("./routes/index.js");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/v1", mainRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});



Here is the github link to my project: https://github.com/iOmKumar30/Mere_Paise_Nikal

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

what is the http status of the request?

Instead of linking to your GitHub repo (Stack Overflow isn't a code-review service), please make your question self-contained.
